# Abnormally slow Haskell code

Tags: haskell

I've been trying to practice with the [Digits-Recognizer](https://github.com/c4fsharp/Dojo-Digits-Recognizer) Dojo in Haskell after having done it in F#. I'm getting results, but for some reason my Haskell code is *insanely* slow, and I cannot seem to find what's wrong.

Here is my code (the `.csv` files can be found on the Dojo's GitHub):

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List
import Data.List.Split
import Data.Ord
import System.IO

type Pixels = [Int]

data Digit = Digit { label  :: Int, pixels :: Pixels }

distance :: Pixels -> Pixels -> Float
distance d1 d2 = sqrt . sum $ map pointDistance $ zip d1 d2
    where pointDistance (a, b) = fromIntegral $ (a - b) * (a - b)

parseDigit :: String -> Digit
parseDigit s = Digit label pixels
    where (label:pixels) = map read $ splitOn "," s

identify :: Digit -> [Digit] -> (Digit, Float)
identify digit training = minimumBy (comparing snd) distances
    where distances = map fn training
          fn ref    = (ref, distance (pixels digit) (pixels ref))

readDigits :: String -> IO [Digit]
readDigits filename = do
    fileContent <- readFile filename
    return $ map parseDigit $ tail $ lines fileContent

main :: IO ()
main = do
    trainingSample <- readDigits "trainingsample.csv"
    validationSample <- readDigits "validationsample.csv"
    let result               = [(d, identify d trainingSample) | d <- validationSample]
        fmt (d, (ref, dist)) = putStrLn $ "Found..."
    mapM_ fmt result
```

**What would be the reason of these bad performances?**

---

**[UPDATE]** Thank you for your many ideas! I have switched my usage of `String` to `Data.Text` and my usage of `List` to `Data.Vector` as suggested, unfortunately the result is still far from satisfactory.

My updated code is [available here](https://gist.github.com/icecrime/caf83a5c9116b4144d91).

To give you a better understanding of my interrogation, here's the output of my Haskell (left) and F# (right) implementation. I'm a total newbie of both languages, so I sincerely believe that there has to be a major mistake in my Haskell version to be *that much* slower.

[image: Terminal capture]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about about working code that is slow. This belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Actually it is **so** slow that I'm not even sure we can consider it's working ;-) But yeah it does compile...

Comment: Have you compiled with optimizations?  Have you tried using the `criterion` package or the threadscope tool to profile your code?  On a guess I'd say it's probably because you're using heavily list-based computations, and lists are notoriously bad at performance, particularly on large data sets like you appear to have.  Have you tried using `Data.Vector` instead of lists?

Comment: A relatively minor point: I see no reason to take square roots.

Comment: You're going to be using your training sample over and over again. There's no reason to read it in lazily, so don't. Moreover, the training sample should not be a list, but rather a Vector, and `Pixels` should be a Vector too.

Comment: Use ```Text``` instead of ```String```, use ```Vector``` instead of lists, change ```Digit``` to ```{ label :: {-# UNPACK #-} ! Int, pixels :: {-# UNPACK #-} ! Pixels }```, compile with optimization, use ```#Int``` instead of Int

Comment: Not a performance suggestion, but note that `map f $ zip xs ys` is just `zipWith f xs ys`.

Comment: First step: switch to ByteString (instead of String) to optimize file reading. With just this change the first "Found..." appears almost instantly and the entire process takes 80 seconds.

Comment: @Ed'ka Thanks, I'll give it a shot (I saw your comment too late and used `Data.Text` instead of `ByteString` for the moment).

Comment: @icecrime you didn't respond to bheklilr, who asked about a painfully common mistake.  Did you compile with the `-O2` flag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're patient, you'll notice that the second result is calculated much faster than the first.  That's because your implementation takes some time to read in the csv files.

You may be tempted to stick a print statement to see when it's done loading like so:

```
main = do
    trainingSample <- readDigits "trainingsample.csv"
    validationSample <- readDigits "validationsample.csv"
    putStrLn "done loading data"
```

But due to lazyIO, this won't do what you think it does. `trainingSample` and `validationSample` are not yet fully evaluated. So your print statement will print almost immediately, and the first result will still take forever.

You can force `readDigits` to fully evaluate their return values, though, which will give you a better idea of how much time is spent there. You could either switch to using non-lazy IO, or just print something derived from the data:

```
readDigits :: String -> IO [Digit]
readDigits filename = do
    fileContent <- readFile filename
    putStr' $ filename ++ ": "
    rows <- forM (tail $ lines fileContent) $ \line -> do
      let xs = parseDigit line
      putStr' $ case compare (sum $ pixels xs) 0 of
                LT -> "-"
                EQ -> "0"
                GT -> "+"
      return xs
    putStrLn ""
    return rows
  where putStr' s = putStr s >> hFlush stdout
```

On my machine, this let me see that it took about 27 seconds to fully read the digits from `trainingsample.csv`.

This is printf-style profiling, which isn't great (much better to use a real profiler, or use criterion to benchmark various parts of your code), but good enough for these purposes.

That's clearly a major part of the slowdown, so it's worth trying to switch to strict io. Using [`Data.Text.IO.readFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.1.1.3/docs/Data-Text-IO.html#v:readFile), which is strict, cut it down to ~18 seconds.

---

UPDATE

Here's how to speed up your updated code:

1. Use unboxed vectors for `Pixels` (small win):

   ```
   import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
   -- ...

   type Pixels = U.Vector Int
   -- ...

   distance :: Pixels -> Pixels -> Float
   distance d1 d2 = sqrt . U.sum $ U.zipWith pointDistance d1 d2
       where pointDistance a b = fromIntegral $ (a - b) * (a - b)

   parseDigit :: T.Text -> Digit
   parseDigit s = Digit label (U.fromList pixels)
       where (label:pixels) = map toDigit $ T.splitOn (T.pack ",") s
             toDigit s      = either (\_ -> 0) fst (T.Read.decimal s)
   ```
2. Force the distance evaluation early by using `seq` (big win):

   ```
   identify :: Digit -> V.Vector Digit -> (Digit, Float)
   identify digit training = V.minimumBy (comparing snd) distances
       where distances = V.map fn training
             fn ref    = let d = distance (pixels digit) (pixels ref) in d `seq` (ref, d)
   ```

On my machine, the whole program now runs in ~5s:

```
% ghc --make -O2 Main.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
Linking Main ...
% time ./Main
./Main  5.00s user 0.11s system 99% cpu 5.115 total
```

The thunks were killing you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I followed your advice, but it's still dramatically slower... I'll have to try with a profile (once I figure out how to use that).

Comment: icecrime: It's the thunks that were killing you; try my update.

Answer (score 3):

Your Vector's version, partially unboxed, adapted for ByteString and compiled with `-O2 -fllvm` runs in 8 seconds on my machine:

```
import Data.Ord
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BC


type Pixels = U.Vector Int

data Digit = Digit { label :: !Int, pixels :: !Pixels }


distance :: Pixels -> Pixels -> Float
distance d1 d2 = sqrt . U.sum . U.zipWith pointDistance d1 $ d2
    where pointDistance a b = fromIntegral $ (a - b) * (a - b)

parseDigit :: B.ByteString -> Digit
parseDigit bs =
    let (label:pixels) = toIntegers bs []
    in Digit label (U.fromList pixels)
    where
      toIntegers bs is =
          let Just (i,bs') = BC.readInt bs
          in if B.null bs' then reverse is else toIntegers (BC.tail bs') (i:is)               

identify :: Digit -> V.Vector Digit -> (Digit, Float)
identify digit training = V.minimumBy (comparing snd) distances
    where distances = V.map fn training
          fn ref    = (ref, distance (pixels digit) (pixels ref))

readDigits :: String -> IO (V.Vector Digit)
readDigits filename = do
    fileContent <- B.readFile filename
    return . V.map parseDigit . V.fromList . tail . BC.lines $ fileContent


main :: IO ()
main = do
    trainingSample <- readDigits "trainingsample.csv"
    validationSample <- readDigits "validationsample.csv"
    let result = V.map (\d -> (d, identify d trainingSample)) validationSample
        fmt (d, (ref, dist)) = putStrLn $ "Found " ++ show (label ref) ++ " for " ++ show (label d) ++ " (distance=" ++ show dist ++ ")"
    V.mapM_ fmt result
```

Output of `+RTS -s`:

```
     989,632,984 bytes allocated in the heap
      19,875,368 bytes copied during GC
      31,016,504 bytes maximum residency (5 sample(s))
      22,748,608 bytes maximum slop
              78 MB total memory in use (1 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      1761 colls,     0 par    0.05s    0.05s     0.0000s    0.0008s
  Gen  1         5 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.02s     0.0030s    0.0085s

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time    7.42s  (  7.69s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.05s  (  0.06s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.01s elapsed)
  Total   time    7.47s  (  7.77s elapsed)

  %GC     time       0.7%  (0.8% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    133,419,569 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  99.3% of total user, 95.5% of total elapsed
```

Comment: not to bikeshed, but why `ByteString` rather than `Text`?

Comment: @rampion Because 'Text' version (icecreame's version at least) is two times slower and uses twice as much memory as my 'ByteString' version (I did not investigate why however). Doesn't look like we need Unicode here anyway.